# How to close a frame that you have and open a new frame in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to open a new frame to show more details and for me to start on a new window like a new fresh page

here is my code:

```
public class OBA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("OBA");
        f.setSize(1366, 768);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

        JLabel l1 = null;
        JLabel l2 = null;
        JLabel l3 = null;
        l1 = new JLabel("Welcome");
        l1.setBounds(625, 100, 100, 100);
        l1.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 22));
        l1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        l2 = new JLabel("To", JLabel.CENTER);
        l2.setBounds(625, 100, 100, 150);
        l2.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 22));
        l2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        l3 = new JLabel("OBA", JLabel.CENTER);
        l3.setBounds(623, 100, 100, 200);
        l3.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 22));
        l3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        f.add(l1);
        f.add(l2);
        f.add(l3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zein, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you tell us what you've tried so far? It's good that you've supplied your code, but it would be even better to see what you have tried to solve your problem, and why it didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

You created a JFrame, `f`, so you know how to create a JFrame. To close that frame for good, you can call `f.dispose()`; if you just want to hide it, call `f.setVisible(false)`. To open a new frame, do something like what you did to create `f`.

I don’t know exactly why you want to do this, but if (as I’ve interpreted your question) you want to close the current window and immediately create a new one, in a lot of situations there’s an easier way. In lieu of disposing one JFrame and creating another, you can keep the existing JFrame and remove whatever’s already in it, such as with successive calls of `f.remove()`, one for each component you want gone. If you put your components in a `LayoutManager` instead of straight into the frame, you could put another `LayoutManager` in with `f.setLayout()` and swap everything out in one go, which might be easier.

For more information on JFrame, see the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

**Edit** (in response to a comment): If you want to wait before changing what’s shown, you need to use a method that causes a delay. `java.lang.thread` has a static method `sleep()` that does exactly this; to wait for five seconds, you can use `Thread.sleep(5000);` (since it accepts milliseconds). This method can throw an exception, though, if you interrupt the thread that’s running `sleep()`. So you should wrap it in a try block:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    // Your thread was interrupted (maybe the user quit the program?)
    // Handle that here.
}
f.remove(/* The element to remove goes here. */);
// Etc...
```

Of course, since this pauses the thread for five seconds, you should not call `sleep()` in a thread that handles things like user input, which could occur during those five seconds.

Oracle has [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for this, too.

This is getting to be a different topic from that of the original question, but threads in Java (and in general) have lots of little intricacies that trip people up. If you need more help with `sleep()` or threading, you might want to ask a new question, or look for an existing one that relates to your problem.

Comment: How do i use the f.remove() because i want my text to wait for 5 seconds then remove everything